# integrate outlook calendar to php app

Tags: php, integration, outlook-calendar

Is there a way to transfer the events setup on outlook calendar to a php app.

Comment: Are you talking manually or automagically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this, except it was to a java webservice. I wrote a .NET sync utility and used Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) to interact with Outlook. The util would run and send certain appointmets to a java webservice and stored in a database for reporting at headquarters.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [**PHP iCalCreator**](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3478.html) which is a class that enables you to parse *ical* files and should be able to display the results.

The links on the website seem to be dead, but search on [**Google**](http://www.google.com) and hopefuly you'll find some leads.

Hope this helps, good luck.